expo camera is not scanning barcode
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';  
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';  
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';  

export const QRCodeScanner = () => {  
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);  
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);  
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);  
  const [text, setText] = useState('');  

  useEffect(() => {  
    (async () => {  
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();  
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');  
    })();  
  }, []);  
  
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {  
    setScanned(true);  
    setText(data);  
  };  
  
  const askForPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    // Camera permissions are still loading.
    return <View />;
  }
  if (!hasPermission) {
    // Camera permissions are not granted yet.
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          We need your permission to show the camera
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={askForPermission} title="Grant Permission" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  const toggleFacing = () => {
    setType(type === Camera.Constants.Type.back ? Camera.Constants.Type.front : Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        style={styles.camera}
        type={type}
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
      />
      {scanned && (
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>QR Code scanned:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.scannedText}>{text}</Text>
          <Button title="Scan Again" onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />
        </View>
      )}
      <Button title="Toggle Facing" onPress={toggleFacing} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 0.5,
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    margin: 10,
  },
  scannedText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    margin: 10,
  },
});

When I give value like this type ={CameraConstants.Type.back}, I get this error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Type' of undefined

When I give value like this  type ={'back'}, I get this error Error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

i tryed consol log Constants it returned undefined
i tryed consol log CameraConstants it returned undefined
can any one help me to fix this or tell me other way to make a QR code scanner

expo-camera has upgraded its version. So instead of using Camera, try using CameraView. I used tailwind for styling.
import * as React from "react";
import { CameraView } from "expo-camera";
import tw from "twrnc";

const Camera: React.FC = () => {
const cameraRef = React.useRef<CameraView>(null);
return (
    <View style={tw`flex-1`}>
      <CameraView
        ref={cameraRef}
       />
    </View>
  );
}
export default Camera;

Here is the documentation link: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/
